# Построение Кривой Гильберта без рекурсии, как?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, pascal, графика, геометрия

Построение Кривой Гильберта без рекурсии, как?

Comment: Вас не затруднит напомнить нам, что такое кривая Гильберта?

Comment: В принципе любую рекурсию можно реализовать в виде цикла.

Answer (score 6):

Вот [вариант на js](http://jsfiddle.net/kazatca/7Zftt/).

```
<canvas id=c width=532 height=532></canvas>
```

-

```
var g = document.getElementById('c').getContext('2d');
var path=[];//массив точек

//нулевой уровень = коробка без стенки слева
path.push({x:0,y:0});
path.push({x:1,y:0});
path.push({x:1,y:1});
path.push({x:0,y:1});
var len=1;//размер нулевого уровня

for(var level=0;level<5;level++){//цикл генерирует кривую пятого уровня
    var cnt=path.length;
    var newpath=[];

    //на каждом уровне делаем четыре копии массива точек так,
    //чтобы в итоге сохранялась правильная последовательность, и тогда в конце их можно будет просто соединить линиями

    for(var i=0;i<cnt;i++){//первую копию транспонируем
        newpath[i]={};
        newpath[i].x=path[i].y;
        newpath[i].y=path[i].x;
    }

    for(var i=cnt;i<cnt*2;i++){//вторую копию просто смещаем вправо
        newpath[i]={};
        newpath[i].x=path[i%cnt].x+len+1;
        newpath[i].y=path[i%cnt].y;
    }

    for(var i=cnt*2;i<cnt*3;i++){//третью копию смещаем вправо вниз
        newpath[i]={};
        newpath[i].x=path[i%cnt].x+len+1;
        newpath[i].y=path[i%cnt].y+len+1;
    }

    for(var i=cnt*3;i<cnt*4;i++){//четвертую копию транспонируем вокруг побочной диагонали и смещаем вниз
        newpath[i]={};
        newpath[i].x=len-path[i%cnt].y;
        newpath[i].y=len-path[i%cnt].x+len+1;
    }

    len=len*2+1;//размер увеличился
    path=newpath;
}

var size=8;//размер отрезка
function line(p0,p1){
  g.beginPath();
    g.moveTo(p0.x*size+2,p0.y*size+2);
    g.lineTo(p1.x*size+2,p1.y*size+2);
    g.stroke();
}

var ind=1;
var cnt=path.length;

function rend(){//красиво рисуем
    if(ind>=cnt)return;
    line(path[ind-1],path[ind]);
    ind++;
    setTimeout(rend,10);
}
rend();

//нет рекурсий
```

Comment: кстати, если внимательно почитать код, там все же есть рекурсия!

Comment: +1, но не за алгоритм (сам умею дофига такого), а за то, что я узнал, что на JS оказывается можно делать графику (да ещё и векторную).

Answer (score 0):

- [Здесь описание и библиотека (не рекурсивный метод)](http://www.tiac.net/~sw/2008/10/Hilbert/moore/index.html)
- [Здесь на русском и на VB (попроще)](http://ref.rushkolnik.ru/v7484/?page=27)
- [На JS](http://my.opera.com/heisenberg16/blog/index.dml/tag/hilbert%20curve%20non%20recursive)

Comment: последняя ссылка довольно хорошая, но алгоритм и назначение коэфф. остается чем-то непонятным. как оно там работает, по моему знает только автор.